# Two double slit experiments after each other

Tags: particle-physics, waves, electrons, double-slit-experiment

Does the act of observation forever destroy a photon or electron's wave like behaviour?

What would the result be if the electron was observed, and instead of displaying the two lines or particle like pattern, we send the particle through another double slit without observing it? Wave or Particle pattern?

noob question sorry. :)

Comment: You observe it, but then you don't?

Comment: Yes. Observe with first double slit, don't observe with second double slit. To test if all possible states collapsed forever with the initial observation.

Comment: Ignoring practical difficulties, you should observe an interference pattern in the second experiment, given that you "release" the particle in a way that does not allow you to know which path it will take.

Comment: I guess I'm just curious as to what observation or bouncing a photon off of, does to the electron. Is it permanent. I'll google some more in the mean time

Comment: Observation puts the particle into an eigenstate of whatever you've observed.  The state then continues to evolve according to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: In order to show wavelike behavior, you have to use many photons and electrons. A single photon passing through a slit in an experiment won't produce a wavelike pattern.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry if it was not clear but that is what I meant. A lot more of them would need to first be measured, and then not - as the second scatter area would be produced from a scatter itself.

Comment: You would get a wave pattern again after the second double slit experiment.